# Sorting in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, use-effect

Good day everyone. I'm trying learn react and have question with sort function. I successfuly got array of objects from database, successufly showed it on page but i cant sort it by fields. I wrote func witch did it but it didnt rerender result.

```
useEffect( () => {
if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) navigate('/signIn')
const getAllAppointments = async () => {
  const response = await store.getAllAppointments();            
  setList(response.data);      
}  
getAllAppointments()    
}, []);
return(
  <table className='appointments-table__list'>
        <tbody>             
          { 
            list             
            .map((task) => 
              {
              const {_id, patient, doctor, date, complaint} = task
              return(                    
                <tr className='appointments-table__line' key={`appointments-${_id}`}>                  
                  <td className='appointments-table__line-cell'>{patient}</td> 
                  <td className='appointments-table__line-cell'>{doctor}</td>
                  <td className='appointments-table__line-cell'><Moment format='DD.MM.YYYY'>{date}</Moment></td>
                  <td className='appointments-table__line-cell'>{complaint}</td>
                  <td className='appointments-table__line-cell'>                       
                  </td>
                </tr>                   
              )                
              })
          }
        </tbody>
)
```

this is part of first component, second component, where i make sorting is here

```
 const Sorting = ({
  list,
  setList  
}) => {  

    //sorting
    const [sortKind, setSortKind] = useState('');
    const [openSortKind, setOpenSortKind] = useState(false);
    const [subtab, setSubtab] = useState(false);
    const [howsort, setHowSort] =useState('asc'); 

  const sort = () => {
    const sortedList = list.sort((a, b) => {
      if (!sortKind || !howsort) {
        return 0;
      }
      if (howsort === 'asc') {        
        if (sortKind) {
          if (a[sortKind] === b[sortKind]) return 0;
          return a[sortKind] > b[sortKind] ? 1 : -1;
        }
      } else {
        if (a[sortKind] === b[sortKind]) return 0;
        return a[sortKind] > b[sortKind] ? -1 : 1;        
      }
    });
    setList(sortedList); 
  }
  
  useEffect( () => {        
    sort();     
  },[sortKind,howsort]);     


  return(
    <form className='sorting-form'>    
      <div className='sorting-block'>
        <div className='kind-sort'>
          <label className='label-kind-sort' htmlFor="select-kind-sort">Сортировать по:</label>
          <select 
            id="select-kind-sort"
            onClick= {() => setOpenSortKind(true)}
            onChange={(e)=>setSortKind(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option></option>          
            {
              fields.map((item, index) => (
                <option 
                  value={item.val} 
                  key={index}               
                >
                  {item.name}
                </option>
              ))        
            }
          </select>
        </div>        
        <div className={openSortKind ? 'direction active' : 'direction '} >
          <label className='label-sort-direction' htmlFor="select-sort-direction">way:</label>
          <select id="select-sort-direction" onChange={(e)=> setHowSort(e.target.value)}>
            <option></option>
            <option value="asc" >asc</option>
            <option value="desc">desc</option>
          </select>
        </div>                    
     </form>
```

I successful got in console log result of sorting, BUT it didnt show on page although I have assigned state value(setList). Can anyone explain why i had this trouble.

P.S. Sorry for my bad knowledge of English)

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue without all the react stuff? It would make it easier to spot the error.

Comment: `sort()` mutates the array in place, and returns a reference to the same array, so you are setting the state with a reference to the previous array which React sees as the same and so doesn't rerender. You'll need to clone the `list` array before sorting. `const sortedList = [...list].sort((a, b) => ...`

Comment: thank you it is work!!!! I cloned the arr it decided my problem!. Thank you very much!